# Problem with running queries with NEST from airflow in BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery

Starting from today queries executed from airflow with bigquery_operator failed when contain NEST in select.
I have a query

```
SELECT
  app_id,
  NEST(country_code) as country_codes
FROM
(
    SELECT
        app_id,
        country_code
    FROM TABLE_DATE_RANGE([project:ds.meta], DATE_ADD(TIMESTAMP('20200812'), -2, 'DAY'), TIMESTAMP('20200812'))
    GROUP BY 
        app_id,
        country_code
)
GROUP BY
  app_id
```

and it imports data from table with scheme

```
[
{"name": "app_id", "type": "string", "mode": "nullable"}, 
{"name": "country_code", "type": "string", "mode": "nullable"}
]
```

to new table with the following expected scheme

```
[
{"name": "app_id", "type": "string", "mode": "nullable"}, 
{"name": "country_codes", "type": "string", "mode": "repeated"}
]
```

flatten_results set to False

Everything was fine until today for years, but today we got the following error:

> Exception: BigQuery job failed. Final error was: {'reason':
> 'invalidQuery', 'location': 'query', 'message': 'Cannot create valid
> output schema for field country_codes. Try renaming country_codes to
> country_codes_group.country_codes in the outermost SELECT.'}.

Seems like BQ can't auto detect scheme from query, but it also not works when I add schema configuration to bigquery_operator. I tried to rerun success queries from past and they also failed.

Comment: Can you just rewrite above in BQ Standard SQL? Anyway, legacy will most likely be retired at all at some point

Comment: It reasonable. As a quick fix I rewrote requests with UDF and started updating requests code to Standart SQL. But it is strange why requests started failing in one day and I don't see new BQ releases on that day.